# Is Html style font-family prioritized by order?

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
<span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    content
</span>
```

Does this mean that there is going to be a priority list for the specified font families on the client, i.e. if no 'Segoe UI' will check for Tahoma, no Tahoma will go for Arial and so on?

Answer with YES or NO will be good enough!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is correct!

Comment: I tried! I think there's a minimum character count or something!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Wouldn't you rather use a stylesheet than embed styles inline like this?

Comment: The long answer is a question, not an answer :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but will still put my 2p worth. Inline styles are sometimes needed. Imagine this is the one and only time you need that style. Why would you add it to a stylesheet?

Answer (score -1):

Yes
If the browser doesn't support the first font then it goes to another. By listing out several fonts you can ensure that the client gets the font you want.
If you want to download a font style, then you can use google fonts.

This is how you get a custom font.

```css
.parent {
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```